# Read the user and permission from excel update in sharepoint site and group

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to read the user name and the access from the excel sheet and update them in a list item level permission.

[image]

Comment: Show us, how you have the values in excel, accordingly we shall help you

Comment: I want to break inheritance and set these excel user permission